# How to test Vkontakte application with local WS?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, vk

I've developed a [Vkontakte](http://vkontakte.ru) application by using Adobe Flex technology with WCF as my server side. The whole thing works perfectly on `localhost`, but after uploading it to Vkontakte - the WS doesn't seem to work and I get this error:

*faultCode:Channel.Security.Error faultString:'Security error accessing url' faultDetail:'Destination: DefaultHTTP'*

How can I solve this problem? How can I test my application on Vkontakte while the WS are still referring to localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I should have used the [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) file to enable the flash file to interact with outside domains.